# How to use NuxtJS SSR build on Amazon CloudFront and ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, nuxt.js, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs

In our project we have been hosting a NuxtJS site on Amazon's ECS using docker repositories. We are now looking into using CloudFront mainly because we want to distribute content worldwide and also use it's compression mechanism.

Has anyone worked with a similar scenario before? Is is possible to host dynamic content on an ECS container and serve it through CloudFront?

Comment: Haven't done it but CloudFront is pretty straight forward. You'd need to give cloudfront the endpoint at which the website is available for example `my-website.com`. If the website isn't hosted on Route53 you need to import your certificate as well. Otherwise CNAME'ing your cloudfront url to your actual webpage won't work. Had this issue when trying to cloudfront a google cloud bucket..

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a similar scenario; running Nuxt in a lambda behind CloudFront. For that scenario you need to connect your nuxt lambda with API Gateway, then add the API Gateway as an Origin in CloudFront. If you want all requests on domain.com/app to hit Nuxt, you then set a CloudFront behaviour to forward  all requests to /app/* to the API Gateway Origin you just added.

So unsure whether you need to front your EC2 with API Gateway, or if you can directly add EC2 as a CloudFront Origin, but look for info on using EC2 as a cloudfront origin and you should be fine.